# How to execute AWS lambda with Open JDK 11+ as custom runtime?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, java-11, openjdk-11

AWS allows to create **Lambda function** with `Java 8` (**OpenJDK 8**) as runtime.
I need to create a simple function using `Open JDK 11`. Something like that:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

public class Hello {
    public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received : " + myCount);
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}
```

There is an option allowing to use a custom runtime and a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html) that contains an example with Shell. However there is no example with `Java`.

Is anyone have already deal with an AWS lambda with custom java runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was also curious as to why we haven't seen any custom runtimes for Java yet, so about a month ago I started playing around with the idea of building one in Java 11 using Jigsaw to produce small runtime. While it's not exactly a tutorial, I did write a fairly detailed Readme on how to build this and the code is simple enough to follow.

Here's my project on GitHub:

https://github.com/andthearchitect/aws-lambda-java-runtime

I just published this recently and it's most certainly a POC so use at your own risk.

Corretto seems interesting but I would guess there will still be people out there who are more comfortable with the official OpenJDK release. I'm hoping maybe this can be the starting point for a production ready open source runtime for Java.

Comment: I also wrote a blog post discussing Custom Runtimes in general and why I created this. It's not a tutorial since I felt it would duplicate a lot of whats in the GitHub readme. But it does go a bit into the details of the runtime: https://andthearchitect.wordpress.com/2019/02/20/running-java-11-on-aws-lambda-using-custom-runtimes/

Answer (score 5):

There's no longer a need to use a custom runtime, as [AWS Lambda now supports Java 11](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-java-11/).

However, Lambda functions that use this runtime will be run with [Amazon Corretto 11](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) and not OpenJDK 11.

If you wish to run your Lambda function with OpenJDK 11 instead of Corretto 11, then using a custom runtime is still recommended.

Answer (score 2):

As **Arun Gupta** [said](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/opensource/amazon-corretto-8-generally-available/), they are working on **Corretto 11** builds corresponding to **Open JDK 11** and will release with time for testing before April, 2019...

However, it is still possible to add a [custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html), which allow to "implement an AWS Lambda runtime in any programming language".

There is no example for `JDK 11` in official AWS documentation, but I found a project, which use a custom runtime of 25MB, build from `JDK 11`, with `jlink`. You can take a look at this [link](https://github.com/ghadishayban/lambdaclj-jdk11)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do that yet. According to AWS:

> "We are working on Corretto 11 builds corresponding to Open JDK 11 and will release with time for testing before April, 2019."

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=875742&tstart=0
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/amazon-corretto-no-cost-distribution-openjdk-long-term-support/

Comment: Totally possible with Custom Runtimes, you can implement the Runtime API in any language. See my answer below.

Comment: Lambda supports custom runtimes.