# aws lambda fails with jdk 11

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, java-11, corretto

I am trying to  build an spring boot application with jdk 11 on   aws lambda.

I followed tutorial on https://dzone.com/articles/aws-lambda-with-spring-boot and code base of  https://github.com/gemerick/spring-boot-lambda/tree/lambda. It worked fine with java 8. Then I changed the 
Runtime: `java8 to java11 in sam.yaml` but deploy failed with following reason

```
        "ResourceStatusReason": "Value java11 at 'runtime' failed to satisfy constraint: 
Member must satisfy enum value set: 
    [java8, nodejs6.10, nodejs8.10, python2.7, python3.6, dotnetcore1.0, dotnetcore2.0, dotnetcore2.1, go1.x] or 
    be a valid ARN (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException;)
```

As far as I understood aws lambda, does not support jdk 11.  Then I read that corretto 11 is out https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/amazon-corretto-11-is-now-generally-available/

Does the release of corretto 11 means that aws-lambda support java 11? I could not see  any official doc about it. It was my first application with aws lambda. Therefore I am bit confused.

Can anyone please point me about support of jdk 11 with aws lambda

Comment: If it doesn't work in your account it's probably not in GA right now.

Comment: @rdas Thanks. I was hoping to find an official documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Java 8 is currently supported in lambda. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model.html

Edit: you can check out how to use Java 11 as a custom runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54799017/4814697

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Lambda now supports Java 11.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-java-11/)

It's also a good idea to add an environment variable to your lambda to speed up start up, unless it's a very high-throughput long-running lambda:

```
Environment:
  Variables:
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: '-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1'
```

I've [blogged](https://codingcraftsman.wordpress.com/2022/03/25/insane-aws-lambda-speed-up-java/) about this